# How to untar multiple tars in to its filename folder in terminal

Tags: linux, tar

For example I have 1000 tar files. (n0001.tar ~ n1000.tar)
I want to untar each file in each filename. (n0001.tar contents in n0001/ folder)

How can I do this in one terminal command?

I assmue this command can be modified.

```
for F in alcatelS*.tar; do
    tar -xvf "$F" 
done
```

Comment: What is the result of your loop ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter expansion to remove the extension from the filename:

```
for F in alcatelS*.tar; do
    dir=${F%.tar}
    ( mkdir "$dir" && cd "$dir" && tar -xvf ../"$F" )
done
```

The `cd` happens in a subshell `(...)` so that the working directory isn't changed for the loop.